# Acid splashing beetle | Germany | Middle Europe

Tags: species-identification

I found a beetle trapped in the bottom of a staircase. When I tried to put it on a paper, it turned and splashed something like acid in my face. I saw drops on my glasses and it begun to burn on my forhead. It escaped then through the drain grate.

It was about 4 cm long and probably brown (not sure about the colour). All I found were the [Brachinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachinus) beetles but they seem to be smaller and I heard no explosion.

Does anybody know what kind of beetle this could have been?

Comment: @SonicSplasher where I live? Germany, Middle Europe (as written in the title)

Comment: oops , didn't really read the location in the title